# Why does my v-select not have any default values even though I am assigning v-model a string

Tags: vue.js

I am editing a vue for a project that I am working on. Below is my code

```
<tr v-for="(program, index) in selectedGantryLocation.pickPrograms">
                    <v-select :items="program"
                              :v-model="selectedGantryLocation.pickProgramValues[index]">
                    </v-select>
 </tr>
```

The `selectedGantryLocation.pickPrograms` is a list of a list of strings. So each "program" that is being used in the iteration is an array of strings, it is nothing more and nothing less. The array generally looks like ["Program1","Program2","Program3" etc.]. The `:items` are being populated correctly and are displayed correctly in the dropdown.

Now because in this vue each dropdown will already have a previously selected value that I am grabbing from the backend, I need each dropdown to show the already selected value. `selectedGantryLocation.pickProgramValues[index]` is indexing a list of strings, each being the default value of each v-select that is created.

For some reason the v-model is not showing any default values. I have verified that the `selectedGantryLocation.pickProgramValues` is indeed populated and filled with strings. Is there an issue with assigning v-model to a string? If that is the case then I do not know how to go about fixing this issue as I have no more properties to reference because I am only working with lists of strings.

I also know that this won't work if the v-model value does not exist in the `:items` but I have also verified that it does exist here so that should not be an issue.

If anyone has any ideas of why my v-selects do not have any default values I would appreciate your feedback, thank you!

Comment: remove : from v-model

Comment: @Radeanu Very silly but this was indeed the mistake